# How to chain completables with closures in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

I would like to do something like

```swift
Completable.empty()
    .andThen { // this does not work
        // run some code
        NSLog("Now pushing objects")
        return Completable.empty // e.g. return api.pushObjects() -> Completable
    }
    .andThen(Completable.empty()) // this is working
    .andThen { // this does not work
        // do something else
        NSLog("Now pulling objects")
        return Completable.empty // e.g. return api.pullObjects() -> Completable
    }
```

`andThen` (or `concat`) does not allow closures as argument. The compiler complains:

```
Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Completable' (aka 'PrimitiveSequence<CompletableTrait, Never>') that does not accept a closure
```

My question is: How to chain completables with closures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. There is no version of `andThen` that takes a closure. The closest you can get to it is this:

```
Completable.empty()
    .andThen(Completable.create(subscribe: { observer in
        print("Now pushing objects")
        observer(.completed)
        return Disposables.create()
    }))
```

Comment: Why is it more complicated to chain Completables than Single<Void>? I don't understand the reason / idea behind...

Comment: A `Single<Void>` emits an onNext event, a `Completable` doesn't. All the basic operators (`map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `scan`) all work on next events only. This makes it easy to work with types where you want to do something on a next event but hard to work with the one type (`Completable`) where you want to work with a completed event _instead_ of a next event. This is why I don't use `Completable`